# Different color of theorem name and theorem number in tcolorbox

Tags: color, theorems, labels, tcolorbox

In the following MWE, how can we change theorem label to `\textcolor{blue}{Theorem}` `\textcolor{magenta}{1}` ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{fonttitle=\color{blue}}{}
\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}{}{}
        How can we change color of theorem label to \textcolor{blue}{Theorem} \textcolor{magenta}{1} ?
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colour of the theorem title is defined by the `coltitle` option, however, since both title and theorem number are set automatically one has to change the number format of the underlying `tcbcounter`.

This can be done with the init option `number freestyle={...}`

Since this option is expanded, the expansion of the code at definition of the theorem must be prevented with `\noexpand`.

For more information about the numbering of boxes with `tcolorbox` see section 5 of the manual, please!

Of course the title background has to be changed as well (use colbacktitle=...) otherwise the title is hard to read!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem[number freestyle={\noexpand\textcolor{magenta}{\noexpand\arabic{\tcbcounter}}}]{theorem}{Theorem}{fonttitle=\color{blue},coltitle=blue}{}


\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}{A nice theorem}{}
        How can we change color of theorem label to \textcolor{blue}{Theorem} \textcolor{magenta}{1} ?
    \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

[image]